# Jooq: How map Record into Pojo class with the same column names?

Tags: java, mapping, pojo, jooq

I have two tables: TABLE_A and TABLE_B, they have some columns with the same names.

```
TABLE_A (ID, NAME, ADDRESS)<br>
TABLE_B (ID, NAME)
```

I want to retrieve all columns from both tables and convert the query result to a Pojo class using Jooq, like following:

```
List<MyPojo> result = query.select()
                         .from(TABLE_A)
                         .join(TABLE_B)
                         .on(TABLE_A.ID.equal(TABLE_B.ID))
                         .fetchInto(MyPojo.class);
```

I want to use the @Column annotation to specify which column comes from which table, but it seems that Jooq does not support this feature. How can I implements this?

```
import javax.persistence.Column;

public class MyPojo {

    @Column(table = "TABLE_A", name = "ID")
    private String idA;

    @Column(table = "TABLE_A", name = "NAME")
    private String nameA;

    @Column(table = "TABLE_A", name = "ADDRESS")
    private String addressA;

    @Column(table = "TABLE_B", name = "ID")
    private String idB;

    @Column(table = "TABLE_B", name = "NAME")
    private String nameB;

}
```

or this,

```
import javax.persistence.Column;

public class MyPojo {

    @Column(name = "TABLE_A.ID")
    private String idA;

    @Column(name = "TABLE_A.NAME")
    private String nameA;

    @Column(name = "TABLE_A.ADDRESS")
    private String addressA;

    @Column(name = "TABLE_B.ID")
    private String idB;

    @Column(name = "TABLE_B.NAME")
    private String nameB;

}
```

Comment: For the record, this question has also been asked here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jooq-user/HCZF9-QIHSc

Answer (score 4):

You could use aliases like so

```
query.select(
   concat(TABLE_A.NAME).as("Aname")
   ...)
  .from(TABLE_A)
  .join(TABLE_B).on(TABLE_A.ID.equal(TABLE_B.ID))
  .fetchInto(MyPojo.class);
```

And use Pojo with annotations like

```
 @Column(name = "Aname")
    private String table_A_name;
```

Comment: I need a dynamic query, so I cannot use column aliases. I will try to write a custom RecordMapper to implement this. Any additional advice is welcome!